# MYSQL - SELECT DateTime closest to full hour, between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that logs a power usage every minute. But due to slow internet connections and some other issues, the logging does not happend on the same second each minute (+- 5 seconds).

I need to collect all the data that is closest to a full hour.

I've got the following query as it is:

```
SELECT * FROM row WHERE time BETWEEN '$today 00:00:00' AND '$today 23:59:59' AND time LIKE '%:59:%' ORDER by time ASC
```

This has an issue though, as the timeline sometimes passes the 59th minute, due to the small offset in the logging period.

How do i make a query, that only selects the values closest to full hours, between a period of time?

*** EDIT 28.10.2016 ***
Heres a small output of the rows, it shows 4 logs around the hour 21:

```
ID      |     VALUE       |         TIME
3002        31260                2016-10-27 21:01:56
3001        31250                2016-10-27 21:00:44
3000        31240                2016-10-27 20:59:33
2999        31234                2016-10-27 20:58:27
```

The desired output, would be the row nearest 21:00:00. In this case the row with id 3000.
The query i posted above, does the trick. However, if the log skips the entry on log 3000, and logs at 20:58:27 and then again at 21:00:44 - It won't show up.

I need this output for all hours between the specified periods.
I would like the output to return all the rows, closest to full hours, as such:

```
ID      |     VALUE       |         TIME
3000        31240                2016-10-27 20:59:33
2500        25000                2016-10-27 19:59:27
2000        20000                2016-10-27 19:00:00
```

Notice how the third outputted row does not contain the 59th minute?

Comment: Can you show us sample input and output?  What does `closest to full hours` actually mean?

Comment: Surely!

The current query outputs values in the following format:
|ID             |    Value    |    Time
 xxxx             xxxx             2016-10-27 06:59:12

Say for instance, that the logging script did not log anyting at 06:59:xx
But logged it at 07:00:01, i would like the closest value to the full hour (07) in this instance.

Comment: This still isn't particularly clear.  Please show a sample input table along with desired output.

Comment: The desired outputs is to have 1 row come out, for each hour that has passed, between the 2 periods of the query.
There should only be 1 row for each hour, with the row nearest to the hour.

I hope this clears it up, as i am unsure on how to produce the tables you asked.

Comment: Show us data from `row` and then show us the output you want.

Comment: Thank you for your patience Tim Biegelsen, i've updated the main question with the info you asked.